# How can I transform one triangle into another triangle with HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: rendering, transformation, terrain-rendering

Given a triangle I'm searching for the canvas transformation to transform it into an other Triangle with the corner coordinates (A,B,C)

**Input triangle:** Red Triangle: A'=(0,0) B'=(80,80) C'=(0,80)
**Output triangle:** Triangle with the coordinates A=(10,30), B=(150,110), C=(50,140)
I'm looking for the transformation that transforms the Input triangle into the output triangle where the points A, B and C should be parameters of the transformation.

The code that transforms the red into the green triangle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/Tarion/mc9mT/ - yet it is obviously wrong because it does not fit the points A,B,C.

What I need is the code or at least the strategy to transform the red triangle it to the triangle that is defined by the given points A,B,C

[image: Triangles]

The green triangle is not the solution but just an (almost) arbitrary transformation of the red one.

Comment: Linearly interpolate (lerp) the points of the red triangle to the positions of the green one, and update the canvas every tick. Done.

Comment: I don't have the green, the goal is that the green triangle fits the points A,B,C

Comment: How much do you know about matrix math in general?

Comment: How is this fundamentally different from your other question? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74849/how-to-transform-a-rectangle-into-a-quadrilateral

Comment: @Tarion Er. I think you are missing the point. You DO have the green, since you obviously know the locations of points A, B and C which define the green triangle you wish to create. No? So use them to animate/lerp the points from those of red (let's call these M, N, O) to A, B, C. Then you will have transformed the triangle. You can lerp / animate your colour from red to green at the same time. Clear?

Comment: No the green does not match A,B,C but it should. ABC do not define the green rectangle, the green rectangle is actually random but should match the point A,B,C. 

I closed my other question, since it's missing the point. I need to transform 2 triangles anyway and not one rectangle.

Comment: @Philipp I know quite a lot about matrix calculation - just missing some practice and praxis applying it.

Comment: Can you rewrite this to very clearly state what information you have (input) and what information you want (output)? I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: Sure, hope that helps :) Sorry for the confusions.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774172/image-manipulation-and-texture-mapping-using-html5-canvas/4774298#4774298 and reproduced it here: http://jsfiddle.net/j2LfS/1/ - pretty nice :) Just remove the duplication mark aand I will post it as answer.

Comment: Finding an answer does not make this question not a duplicate. Since it's marked as duplicate, you should post an answer to the question this question is a duplicate of.

Comment: ... that question is deleted. So there is no duplicate.